# How to achieve idempotency in a POST method that you do not control?

Tags: rest, api, http-post, idempotent

I am planning to consume a HTTP POST method, that by default, is not idempotent.
As I don't have any control over this API, how is the correct way to guarantee that I will not create duplicate entries on the server?
I can think in only one way:
1. Check if the resource exists on the server side. I suppose that I could make this check only when retrying.
2. If not, make a HTTP POST to create the resource

Is there any way to guarantee that I will no create duplicate entries ?

Comment: will someone else have the same problem? i.e. they can duplicate resources that you have already created? Or is the issue only related to resources you create?

Answer (score 1):

> how is the correct way to guarantee that I will not create duplicate entries on the server?

You cannot guarantee it without support from the message handler.

There are two problems; first - even on the happy path, there is a window between the time that you *check* and the time that you *update*, during which things can be changing a the remote host.

Second, if the network is unreliable, a message can be delayed.  You send a request to create the new resource and that request is lost.  You check, try again, and successfully create the resource.  Now your *original* request re-appears and is delivered to the server.

Check before use may well *reduce* the number of duplicates to an acceptable tolerance, but it cannot *guarantee* exactly once.